# spring - constructor injection and overriding parent definition of nested bean

Tags: java, spring

I've read the Spring 3 reference on [inheriting bean definitions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions), but I'm confused about what is possible and not possible.

For example, a bean that takes a collaborator bean, configured with the value 12

```
<bean name="beanService12" class="SomeSevice">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="serviceCollaborator1"/>
</bean>

<bean name="serviceCollaborator1" class="SomeCollaborator">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="12"/> 
    <!-- more cargs, more beans, more flavor -->
</bean>
```

I'd then like to be able to create similar beans, with slightly different configured collaborators. Can I do something like

```
   <bean name="beanService13" parent="beanService12">
       <constructor-arg index="0">
          <bean>
             <constructor-arg index="0" value="13"/>
          </bean>
       </constructor>
   </bean>
```

I'm not sure this is possible and, if it were, it feels a bit clunky. Is there a nicer way to override small parts of a large nested bean definition? It seems the child bean has to know quite a lot about the parent, e.g. constructor index.

This is a toy example - in practice the service is a large bean definition relying on many other collaborator beans, which have also other bean dependencies. For example, a chain of handlers were created with each bean referencing the next in the chain, which references the next. I want to create an almost identical chain with some small changes to handlers in the middle, how do I it?

I'd prefer not to change the structure - the service beans use collaborators to perform their function, but I can add properties and use property injection if that helps.

This is a repeated pattern, would creating a custom schema help?

Thanks for any advice!

EDIT: The nub of my question is, if I have a really large bean definition, with a complex hiearchy of beans being created (bean having properites that are bean etc.), and I want to create a bean that is almost the same with a few changes, how to I do it? Please mention if your solution has to use properites, or if constructor injection can be used.

Nested vs. top-level beans are not the issue (in fact, I think all the beans are top level in practice.)

EDIT2: Thank you for your answers so far. A FactoryBean might be the answer, since that will reduce the complexity of the spring context, and allow me to specify just the differences as parameters to the factory. But, pushing a chunk of context back into code doesn't feel right. I've heard that spring can be used with scripts, e.g. groovy - does that provide an alternative? Could the factory be created in groovy?

Comment: Are you creating your "slightly different configured collaborators" dynamically, or only at startup (via the spring beans xml)?

Comment: Just at startup. It's a large bean def, with collaborators wired to more collaborators. And then about 4 instances of this where I want to change a few bean properties on some deeply nested beans. (The nesting is in terms of the object model - all the spring beans are declared at the top level.)

Comment: why not expose your collaborators as top level beans?  You can use the prototype scope along with the parent bean pattern, although I think it would be the same as abstract.  SingleShot seems to have the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. I don't think you can achieve exactly what you want without creating your own custom schema (which is non-trivial for nested structures), but the following example is probably pretty close without doing that.

First, define an abstract bean to use as a template for your outer bean (my example uses a Car as the outer bean and an Engine as the inner bean), giving it default values that all other beans can inherit:

```
<bean id="defaultCar" class="Car" abstract="true">
    <property name="make" value="Honda"/>
    <property name="model" value="Civic"/>
    <property name="color" value="Green"/>
    <property name="numberOfWheels" value="4"/>
    <property name="engine" ref="defaultEngine"/>
</bean>
```

Since all Honda Civics have the same engine (in my world, where I know nothing about cars), I give it a default nested engine bean. Unfortunately, a bean cannot reference an abstract bean, so the default engine cannot be abstract. I've defined a concrete bean for the engine, but mark it as `lazy-init` so it will not actually be instantiated unless another bean uses it:

```
<bean id="defaultEngine" class="Engine" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="numberOfCylinders" value="4"/>
    <property name="volume" value="400"/>
    <property name="weight" value="475"/>
</bean>
```

Now I can define my specific car, taking all the default values by referencing the bean where they are defined via `parent`:

```
<bean id="myCar" parent="defaultCar"/>
```

My wife has a car just like mine, except its a different model (again, I know nothing about cars - let's assume the engines are the same even though in real life they probably are not). Instead of redefining a bunch of beans/properties, I just extend the default car definition again, but override one of its properties:

```
<bean id="myWifesCar" parent="defaultCar">
    <property name="model" value="Odyssey"/>
</bean>
```

My sister has the same car as my wife (really), but it has a different color. I can extend a concrete bean and override one or more properties on it:

```
<bean id="mySistersCar" parent="myWifesCar">
    <property name="color" value="Silver"/>
</bean>
```

If I liked racing minivans, I might consider getting one with a bigger engine. Here I extend a minivan bean, overriding its default engine with a new engine. This new engine extends the default engine, overriding a few properties:

```
<bean id="supedUpMiniVan" parent="myWifesCar">
    <property name="engine">
        <bean parent="defaultEngine">
            <property name="volume" value="600"/>
            <property name="weight" value="750"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can also do this more concisely by using [nested properties](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conventions):

```
<bean id="supedUpMiniVan" parent="myWifesCar">
    <property name="engine.volume" value="600"/>
    <property name="engine.weight" value="750"/>
</bean>
```

This will use the "defaultEngine". However, if you were to create two cars this way, each with different property values, the behavior will not be correct. This is because the two cars would be sharing the same engine instance, with the second car overriding the property settings set on the first car. This can be remedied by marking the defaultEngine as a "prototype", which instantiates a new one each time it is referenced:

```
<bean id="defaultEngine" class="Engine" scope="prototype">
    <property name="numberOfCylinders" value="4"/>
    <property name="volume" value="400"/>
    <property name="weight" value="475"/>
</bean>
```

I think this example gives the basic idea. If your data structure is complex, you might define multiple abstract beans, or create several different abstract hierarchies - especially if your bean hierarchy is deeper than two beans.

Side note: my example uses properties, which I believe are much clearer to understand, both in Spring xml and in Java code. However, the exact same technique works for constructors, factory methods, etc.

Comment: This looks promising, although I will have to add properties to my beans - I'm presently using constructor injection. I read that spring supports nested properties syntax. Can a child bean definition override the parent using nested properties, e.g.

<property name="engine.weight" value="800"/>. Then I don't need to know about what bean is already instantiated when I override.

Comment: constructor injection is pretty much the worst way to go with spring imho.

Comment: @Justin - couldn't agree more - using constructors places so many restrictions, it's hard to read and don't work on a friday. I'll be glad to change to property injection. The original code predates spring and spring was grafted into it. At the time spring was new and there was no clear advice which style of injection to choose, so we stuck with c'tor injection, but over time, advice sided more and more with properties injection.

Comment: @mdma - yes, you can use nested properties, which I didn't know about until you asked :-)

Comment: @Singleshot - That's good news. I can't remember where I read about the nested properties, and didn't find it in the spring reference when I searched. It would really help if you could post a link and extend your sample to include a nested property override.

Comment: @mdma - Done! Link and nest properties example added towards the end.

Answer (score 6):

Your example will not work as specified, because the nested bean definition has no `class` or `parent` specified. You'd need to add more information, like this:

```
<bean name="beanService13" parent="beanService12">
   <constructor-arg index="0">
      <bean parent="beanBaseNested">
         <constructor-arg index="0" value="13"/>
      </bean>
   </constructor>
```

Although I'm not sure if it's valid to refer to nested beans by name like that.

Nested bean definitions should be treated with caution; they can quickly escalate into unreadability. Consider defining the inner beans as top-level beans instead, which would make the outer bean definitions easier to read.

As for the child beans needing to know the constructor index of the parent bean, that's a more basic problem with Java constructor injection, in that Java constructor arguments cannot be referred to by name, only index. Setter injection is almost always more readable, at the cost of losing the finality of constructor injection.

A custom schema is always an option, as you mentioned, although it's a bit of a pain to set up. If you find yourself using this pattern a lot, it might be worth the effort.

Comment: You may want to look at ApplicationContextAware, and use context scanning to build up your handler chain (in your bean init method), rather than building it up through constructor args.

Comment: Would that work if all the handlers implement the same interface?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using a factory instead?

You can config beans to have a factory and you could encode the varying parameters in the factory creation...

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the factory pattern from Patrick:  you can use a prototype bean to get pre-wired dependencies:

```
<bean id="protoBean" scope="prototype">
 <property name="dependency1" ref="some bean" />
 <property name="dependency2" ref="some other bean" />
 ...
</bean>
```

Now, this works best if you use setter injection (rather than constructor arguments), i'm not sure you can even do it you require constructor args.

```
public class PrototypeConsumingBean implements ApplicationContextAware {

 public void dynmicallyCreateService(String serviceParam) {
   // creates a new instance because scope="prototype"
   MyService newServiceInstance = (MyService)springContext.getBean("protoBean");
   newServiceInstance.setParam(serviceParam);
   newServiceInstance.mySetup();
   myServices.add(newServiceInstance);
 }

 public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
  m_springContext = ctx;
 }
}
```

Comment: I considered using a factory, and I'm ambivilent - I am torn between wanting to keep the spring config simple and keeping construction/configuration out of my code. Using a factory will push a big chunk of the wiring back into the code.

Comment: Yea, the factory pattern only makes sense if you are creating your complex beans dynamically.  If you can do everything through spring the above pattern doesn't pay off; it wasn't exactly clear from the original question what you required.