# Spring IOC nested bean in template override property value

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

i have a `template bean` which have a nested `bean`. The nested bean have 2 important properties the one which is valid for the others 3 beans definitions but they have a secong property which change in each bean.

my template looks like this. a bean with no class.

```
<bean id="myBeanTemplate" abstract="true" scope="prototype">
    <property name="school">        
        <bean class="com.model.School" scope="prototype">
            <property name="status" value="true"/><!--is all the same for all the child beans..->
            /*address=?? the property which is change across the children beans.. the property to  be set*/
        </bean>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

here i dont set the `addres` property just because they vary in the following bean declaration all i wanna do is has the bean template above and `override the address property only`. just like this.

```
<bean id="myBeanForStudentsInSchool13" class="com.model.Students" parent="myBeanTemplate" scope="prototype">    
       here i want to set the address property to a value   
</bean>

<bean id="myBeanForStudentsInSchool23" class="com.model.Students" parent="myBeanTemplate" scope="prototype">    
       here i want to set the address property a different value    
</bean>
```

but like is a nested bean i dont know how to reference it...

*UPDATE*

i am allowed use just declarative configuration...

thanks a lot..

Comment: You can't get access to a nested bean.

Comment: Why not make public (no-nested) and prototype the nested bean?. "Perhaps" (I am not sure) being abstract, it to let the child override it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this solution with Java Config.

School model:

```
public class School {

    private boolean status;
    private String address;

    // getters & setters

}
```

Bean template:

```
public abstract class MyBeanTemplate {

    private School school;

    public School getSchool() {
        return school;
    }

    public void setSchool(School school) {
        this.school = school;
    }

}
```

Students class:

```
public class Students extends School {

}
```

Spring configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Students myBeanForStudentsInSchool13() {
        Students students = new Students();
        students.setAddress("myBeanForStudentsInSchool13");

        return students;
    }

    @Bean
    public Students myBeanForStudentsInSchool23() {
        Students students = new Students();
        students.setAddress("myBeanForStudentsInSchool23");

        return students;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For XML configuration check this example (notice dots in child bean):

```
<bean id="myBeanTemplate" abstract="true" class="com.beans.MyBeanTemplate">
    <property name="school">
        <bean class="com.model.School">
            <property name="status" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myBeanForStudentsInSchool13" class="com.model.Students" parent="myBeanTemplate">    
    <property name="school.address" value="myBeanForStudentsInSchool13"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myBeanForStudentsInSchool23" class="com.model.Students" parent="myBeanTemplate">    
    <property name="school.address" value="myBeanForStudentsInSchool23"/>
</bean>
```

You can also check a more detailed answer here: [spring - constructor injection and overriding parent definition of nested bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799411/spring-constructor-injection-and-overriding-parent-definition-of-nested-bean)

Comment: i am allowed just use declarative configuration.